# Standard Keyboard Driver Source Code - Where can I find this?

Tags: c++, vb.net, keyboard, driver

I am looking for the standard source code for a keyboard.  Is there any where that I can download this source code so that I can modify it for my own use?

Answer (score 2):

No such thing as "standard source code" for a keyboard.  Here's a page on the Linux keyboard driver: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1080

Comment: Thank you.  Would these codes also work for a Windows application?

Comment: Not at all. But note that a Windows Application can't be used as a keyboard driver anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your best chance for a Windows keyboard driver will probably be to get the Windows DDK (Device Driver development Kit). OTOH, based on the questions' tags (especially vb.net) I'm left wondering exactly why you'd want that. The keyboard driver itself mostly just gets activated when the user presses a key, gets the data, and goes back to sleep. If you're interested in something like mapping keys to different characters, that's not in the keyboard driver itself at all (without even looking at any code for the driver itself).

Comment: To make it more explicit: keyboard drivers **must** be kernel drivers (as they're used during boot) and kernel drivers **cannot** use .Net.